# Can't Get Network Connection In Testing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

When I start debugging using my iphone to test the app I'm making, it always returns no network connection, I know that I have one. It's set up correctly.

I am VERY new to this so please be gentle.

In the code below, the 
`if (defaultNetworkAvailable && ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsDirect) != 0))`
always returns false.

```
{
    public class NetworkConnection :INetworkConnection
    {
        public bool IsConnected { get; set; }

        public void CheckNetworkConnection()
        {
            InternetStatus();
        }

        public bool InternetStatus()
        {
            NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
            bool defaultNetworkAvailable = IsNetworkAvailable(out flags);

            if (defaultNetworkAvailable && ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsDirect) != 0))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (flags == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private event EventHandler ReachabilityChanged;
        private void OnChange(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
        {
            var h = ReachabilityChanged;
            if(h != null)
            {
                h(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        private NetworkReachability defaultReachability;
        public bool IsNetworkAvailable(out NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
        {
            if(defaultReachability == null)
            {
                defaultReachability = new NetworkReachability(new System.Net.IPAddress(0));
                defaultReachability.SetNotification(OnChange);
                defaultReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
            }
            if(!defaultReachability.TryGetFlags(out flags))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection(flags);
        }

        private bool IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
        {
            bool isReachable = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) != 0;
            bool noConnectionRequired = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionRequired) == 0;

            if ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) != 0)
                noConnectionRequired = true;
            return isReachable && noConnectionRequired;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking for `isDirect`?  Is the host you are using for testing reachability supposed to be on your local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out why `if (defaultNetworkAvailable && ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsDirect) != 0))` always returns false. You can print `defaultNetworkAvailable` and `flags` on your side to find out where is the problem.

When I run your code, I get:

```
defaultNetworkAvailable = true;
flags = NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable;
```

So, it didn't return false to me.

Here are document of [networkreachabilityflags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/systemconfiguration.networkreachabilityflags?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).

In addition, I would recommend you to use [xamarin/essentials/connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios) to test `Netconnection`. It's easier.

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    // Connection to internet is available
}
```

Here is [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Cios) about how to use `Xamarin.Essentials`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. I will try the Xamarin.Essentials when I get back to work on it this evening.

Comment: This worked amazingly, it does everything (I think) I was trying to do with all that other code. Thanks for helping me out! Xamarin.Essentials is the best move for me here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to check for Internet access, you can use simple helper without any plugin.

```
    internal static bool IsInternetAvailable()
    {
        try
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            String host = "google.com";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
            int timeout = 4000;
            PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```